# winhttp client and openssl server communication error

Tags: c++, sockets, https, openssl, winhttp

I have encounted a strange communication problem when using winhttp to program http client and using openssl to program http server.

I use wireshark to analyze the communication. Everything seems ok when handshake between the two, and the handshake procedure is really quick. But after the handshake, winhttp client taken a really long time send a http request, then server received the request (the received packet is right) then server attempted to send response with ssl_write, but client cannot receive this packet.

please see notes in my code for advanced info.

Below is client's main communication code.

```
BOOL CHttpClient :: _Synchronize(BYTE* pbRequest, DWORD dwRequestCb, 
                                 BYTE** pbResponse, DWORD* dwResponseCb)
{
    DWORD   dwErrorCode      = 0;
    DWORD   dwStatusCode     = 0;
    DWORD   dwSize           = sizeof(DWORD);
    DWORD   dwLastStatusCode = 0;
    BOOL    bDone            = FALSE;

    if (FALSE == DoConnectAndOpenRequest(dwRequestCb == 0))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (!bDone)
    {
        if (!WinHttpSendRequest(m_hRequest, NULL, 0, pbRequest, dwRequestCb, dwRequestCb, NULL))
        {
            dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
            switch (dwErrorCode)
            {
                case ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT:
                case ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT:
                    m_dwDefaultAddrIndex = (m_dwDefaultAddrIndex + 1) % m_lpConfig->dwHttpAddrNum;

                case ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR:
                    if (FALSE == DoConnectAndOpenRequest(dwRequestCb == 0))
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                    continue;

                case 12175:
                    continue;

                case ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED:
                    continue;

                default:
                    return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // client always wait here for server's response and get a error code as 12002--ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT 
        if (!WinHttpReceiveResponse(m_hRequest, NULL))
        {
            dwErrorCode = GetLastError();  // get error code 12002--ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT 
            switch (dwErrorCode)
            {
                case ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST:
                    continue;

                case ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED:
                    continue;

                default:
                    if (FALSE == DoConnectAndOpenRequest(dwRequestCb == 0))
                    {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (!DoServerAuth())
        {
            m_dwDefaultAddrIndex = (m_dwDefaultAddrIndex + 1) % m_lpConfig->dwHttpAddrNum;
            if (FALSE == DoConnectAndOpenRequest(dwRequestCb == 0))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if (!WinHttpQueryHeaders(m_hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                    NULL, &dwStatusCode, &dwSize, NULL))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        switch (dwStatusCode)
        {
            // success
            case 200:
                bDone = TRUE;
                break;

            // proxy need authentication
            case 407:
                if (dwLastStatusCode == 407)
                {
                    bDone = TRUE;
                }
                else if (!DoProxyAuth())
                    return FALSE;
                break;

            default:
                return FALSE;
            }
            dwLastStatusCode = dwStatusCode;
        }

        DWORD dwBytesAvailable  = 0;
        DWORD dwBytesTransfered = 0;
        BYTE* pbTmpBuf = new BYTE [GetMaxTransferCb()];

        // read http server reply
        *dwResponseCb = 0;
        do 
        {
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(m_hRequest, &dwBytesAvailable))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            if (!WinHttpReadData(m_hRequest, pbTmpBuf + *dwResponseCb, dwBytesAvailable, 
                &dwBytesTransfered))
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
            *dwResponseCb += dwBytesTransfered;
        } while (dwBytesAvailable > 0);

        *pbResponse = new BYTE [*dwResponseCb];
        memcpy(*pbResponse, pbTmpBuf, *dwResponseCb);
        RELEASE_ARRAY(pbTmpBuf);

        // all done
        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL CHttpClient :: DoConnectAndOpenRequest(BOOL bGetVerb)
    {
        BOOL   bOK              = FALSE;
        DWORD  dwReqObjNameCch  = (DWORD)rand() % (20 - 5) + 5;
        BYTE*  lpReqObjName     = new BYTE [(dwReqObjNameCch + 6) * sizeof(TCHAR)];
        DWORD  dwOptionCode     = 0;

        __try
        {
            // release old handles
            RELEASE_HINTERNET(m_hConnect);
            RELEASE_HINTERNET(m_hRequest);

            // connect to default address, change of default address is not my duty
            if (NULL == (m_hConnect = WinHttpConnect(m_hSession, 
                m_lpConfig->lpHttpAddrs[m_dwDefaultAddrIndex].tszAddr, 
                m_lpConfig->lpHttpAddrs[m_dwDefaultAddrIndex].wPort, 0)))
                __leave;

            // random generate request object name
            // now this method is slow and bad, we can improve later
            if (!CryptGenRandom(m_hCryptProv, dwReqObjNameCch * sizeof(TCHAR), lpReqObjName))
                return FALSE;
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwReqObjNameCch * sizeof(TCHAR); i += sizeof(TCHAR))
            {
                lpReqObjName[i]     = (lpReqObjName[i] % 26) + 97;
                lpReqObjName[i + 1] = 0;
            }
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch]     = _T('.');
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch + 1] = _T('h');
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch + 2] = _T('t');
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch + 3] = _T('m');
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch + 4] = _T('l');
            ((LPTSTR)lpReqObjName)[dwReqObjNameCch + 5] = 0;

            // open request
            if (NULL == (m_hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(m_hConnect, bGetVerb ? L"GET" : L"POST", 
                (LPTSTR)lpReqObjName, L"HTTP/1.1", WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE)))
                __leave;

            // set cert options
            if (m_lpConfig->bSsl)
            {
                dwOptionCode = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | 
                               SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
                if (!WinHttpSetOption(m_hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwOptionCode, 
                    sizeof(DWORD)))
                    __leave;
            }

            // all done
            bOK = TRUE;
        }
        __finally
        {
            if (!bOK)
            {
                RELEASE_HINTERNET(m_hConnect);
                RELEASE_HINTERNET(m_hRequest);
            }
            RELEASE_ARRAY(lpReqObjName);
        }

        return bOK;
    }
```

Below is server's main communication code

```
    #include <strsafe.h>

    BOOL CSslServer :: StartService(SSL_CONFIG* lpSslServerConfig)
    {
        WSADATA lpWSAData;
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &lpWSAData);

        CRYPTO_malloc_init();           // Initialize malloc, free, etc for OpenSSL's use
        SSL_library_init();             // Initialize OpenSSL's SSL libraries
        SSL_load_error_strings();       // Load SSL error strings
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();   // Load all available encryption algorithms

        m_lpConfig = lpSslServerConfig;
        m_SslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_server_method());
        SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(m_SslCtx, (void*)"123456");
        if (1 > SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(m_SslCtx, m_lpConfig->szCertFileDir, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (1 > SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(m_SslCtx, m_lpConfig->szSkeyFileDir, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(m_SslCtx, "ALL");
        SSL_CTX_set_verify(m_SslCtx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);

        if (NULL == (m_hServerQuitEvt = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL)))
            return FALSE;

        if (NULL == (m_hWorkThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SslServerWorkThread, this, 0, NULL)))
        {
            StopService();
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    BOOL CSslServer :: StopService()
    {
        DWORD dwExitCode = 0;

        if (m_hWorkThread != NULL)
        {
            SetEvent(m_hServerQuitEvt);
            WaitForSingleObject(m_hWorkThread, 30000);
            if(GetExitCodeThread(m_hWorkThread, &dwExitCode))
            {
                if(dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
                    TerminateThread(m_hWorkThread, 0);
            }
        }

        SSL_CTX_free(m_SslCtx);
        RELEASE_HANDLE(m_hServerQuitEvt);
        RELEASE_HANDLE(m_hWorkThread);
        m_WorkThreadList.empty();
        return TRUE;
    }

    DWORD WINAPI SslServerWorkThread(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        CSslServer*  lpServer      = (CSslServer*)lpParam;
        SOCKET       hListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        TIMEVAL*     lpWaitTime    = new TIMEVAL;
        fd_set       ListenFds;
        DWORD        dwWaitForQuit = 0;
        int          nSelectRel    = 0;
        int          nSize         = 0;

        SESSION_CONTEXT* lpSessionCtx = NULL;
        WORK_THREAD_CONTEXT* lpWorkThreadCtx = NULL;

        hListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        bind(hListenSocket, (sockaddr*)&lpServer->m_lpConfig->SslServerAddr, 
            sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        if (SOCKET_ERROR == listen(hListenSocket, SOMAXCONN))
        {
            RELEASE_SOCKET(hListenSocket);
            RELEASE(lpWaitTime);
            return 0;
        }

        FD_ZERO(&ListenFds);
        FD_SET(hListenSocket, &ListenFds);
        lpWaitTime->tv_sec  = 30;
        lpWaitTime->tv_usec = 0;

        do 
        {
            nSelectRel = select(0, &ListenFds, NULL, NULL, lpWaitTime);
            switch (nSelectRel)
            {
            case SOCKET_ERROR:
                goto END;

            case 1:
                lpSessionCtx = new SESSION_CONTEXT;
                nSize = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
                if (INVALID_SOCKET == (lpSessionCtx->hClientSocket = accept(hListenSocket, 
                    (struct sockaddr *)&lpSessionCtx->ClientAddress, &nSize)))
                {
                    RELEASE(lpSessionCtx);
                    goto END;
                }

                lpSessionCtx->lpServer = lpServer;
                lpSessionCtx->lpWorkConfig = lpServer->m_lpConfig->lpWorkConfig;
                lpSessionCtx->SslSession = SSL_new(lpServer->m_SslCtx);
                SSL_set_fd(lpSessionCtx->SslSession, lpSessionCtx->hClientSocket);
                SSL_accept(lpSessionCtx->SslSession);

                lpWorkThreadCtx = new WORK_THREAD_CONTEXT;
                lpWorkThreadCtx->hWorkThreadQuitEvt = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
                lpWorkThreadCtx->hWorkThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkMain, lpSessionCtx,
                    0, NULL); 
                // WorkMain is not provided here, the function just analyze the received packet and 
                // invoke SendPacket to send response.
                lpSessionCtx->lpWorkThreadCtx = lpWorkThreadCtx;
                lpServer->m_WorkThreadList.push_back(lpWorkThreadCtx);
                break;

            default:
                FD_SET(hListenSocket, &ListenFds);
            }

            dwWaitForQuit = WaitForSingleObject(lpServer->m_hServerQuitEvt, 0);
            if (dwWaitForQuit == WAIT_FAILED || dwWaitForQuit == WAIT_ABANDONED)
            {
                goto END;
            }
        } while (dwWaitForQuit != WAIT_OBJECT_0);

    END:
        RELEASE_SOCKET(hListenSocket);
        RELEASE(lpWaitTime);

        return 0;
    }

    // I have examined the received packet. This function is ok
    BOOL CSslServer :: ParseClientPacket(SSL* ssl, BYTE** lpBuf, DWORD* dwTransCb)
    {
        char* lpHeader     = NULL;
        BOOL  bOk          = FALSE;
        int   nRet         = 0;
        int   nHeaderBufCb = 1024;
        int   nIndex       = 0;
        DWORD dwPackBufCb  = 0;

        __try
        {
            *dwTransCb = 0;

            lpHeader = new char [nHeaderBufCb];
            memset(lpHeader, 0, nHeaderBufCb);
            if (0 >= (nRet = SSL_read(ssl, lpHeader, nHeaderBufCb))) 
                __leave;
            nHeaderBufCb = lstrlenA(lpHeader);

            for (nIndex = 20; nIndex < nHeaderBufCb - 15; nIndex++)
            {
                if (0 == memcmp(lpHeader + nIndex, "Content-Length: ", 16))
                {
                    sscanf_s(lpHeader + nIndex + 16, "%d", &dwPackBufCb);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (nIndex == nHeaderBufCb - 15)
                __leave;

            for (nIndex += 16; nIndex < nHeaderBufCb - 4; nIndex++)
            {
                if (0 == memcmp(lpHeader + nIndex, "\r\n\r\n", 4))
                    break;
            }
            if (nIndex == nHeaderBufCb - 4)
                __leave;

            *lpBuf = new BYTE [dwPackBufCb];
            if (nRet - nIndex - 4 > 0)
            {
                memcpy(*lpBuf, lpHeader + nIndex + 4, nRet - nIndex - 4);
                *dwTransCb = nRet - nIndex - 4;
            }
            while (*dwTransCb < dwPackBufCb)
            {
                if (0 >= SSL_read(ssl, *lpBuf + *dwTransCb, dwPackBufCb - *dwTransCb))
                {
                    bOk = TRUE;
                    __leave;
                }
                *dwTransCb += nRet;
            }

            bOk = TRUE;
        }
        __finally
        {
            RELEASE_ARRAY(lpHeader);
        }

        return bOk;
    }

    BOOL CSslServer :: SendPacket(SSL* ssl, BYTE* lpBuf, DWORD cb)
    {
        LPSTR lpHttpPacket = NULL;
        DWORD dwHeaderLen  = 0;
        BOOL  bOk          = FALSE;
        char  szTime[50]   = {0};
        time_t     lTime;
        struct tm  GmtTime;

        __try
        {
            lpHttpPacket = new char [200 + cb];
            memset(lpHttpPacket, 0, 200 + cb);

            time(&lTime);
            _gmtime64_s(&GmtTime, &lTime);
            strftime(szTime, 50, "Date: %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT\r\n", &GmtTime);

            StringCchPrintfA(lpHttpPacket, 200, 
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/8.0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n%sContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", 
                szTime, cb);
            dwHeaderLen = lstrlenA(lpHttpPacket);

            memcpy(lpHttpPacket + dwHeaderLen, lpBuf, cb);
            if (0 >= SSL_write(ssl, lpHttpPacket, cb)) // the packet send by this sentence cannot be received by client
                __leave;                                 // observe by wireshark, this sentence send a ssl reassembled pdu
            bOk = TRUE;
        }
        __finally
        {
            RELEASE_ARRAY(lpHttpPacket);
        }

        return bOk;
    }
```

And below is wireshark snap.

```
NO.        Time      Source   Destination  Protocol  Length       Info

15951    3691.1       .23      .98          SSL       126     client hello

15952    3691.1       .98      .23         SSLv3      1109    server hello

15953    3691.1       .23      .98         SSLv3      386     client key exchange, change cipher spec, finished

15954    3691.1       .98      .23         SSLv3      121     change cipher spec, finished

16029    3706.6       .23      .98          http      301     POST ...... HTTP/1.1

16060    3711.9       .98      .23         SSLv3       83     [SSL segment of a ressembled PDU]
```

It takes me really a long time to solve this problem. I really hope someone and handle this.

best wishes

Comment: Did you check whether `SSL_write` writes out all the data available to write? Also its good practice to check the return value of `SSL_connect` and `SSL_accept`.

Comment: as you have noticed, I have checked the return value of SSL_accept and SSL_write, and I surprise saw the return value of SSL_write is just 8. Then I check the code, and found a small but fatal program error in my code, I have given a wrong param to SSL_write. After fix this error, the communication is alright. This is a lesson. Thank you!

Comment: Could you trim your post to just the relevant portions of the code? Functions like `StartService` and `StopService` don't appear to be relevant based on your description. Wading through a dump of your client and server projects is a lot to ask.